# Cruisecontrol SVN proxy issue

Tags: svn, proxy, cruisecontrol

When cruisecontrol start an svnbootstrapper an exception is logged in the cruisecontrol log file.

---

2009-07-07 14:29:41,942 [BuildQueueThread] INFO  BuildQueue       - now adding to the thread queue: trunk-edumatic-3-framework-client
2009-07-07 14:29:41,942 [Thread-25] INFO  Project          - Project trunk-edumatic-3-framework-client:  bootstrapping
2009-07-07 14:29:41,942 [Thread-25] INFO  ProjectController - trunk-edumatic-3-framework-client Controller: build progress event: bootstrapping
2009-07-07 14:30:03,615 [Thread-26] WARN  SVNBootstrapper  - svn: OPTIONS of 'repo-url': could not connect to server (host)
2009-07-07 14:30:03,725 [Thread-25] INFO  Project          - Project trunk-edumatic-3-framework-client:  idle
2009-07-07 14:30:03,725 [Thread-25] INFO  ProjectController - trunk-edumatic-3-framework-client Controller: build progress event: idle
2009-07-07 14:30:03,725 [Thread-25] ERROR Project          - exception attempting build in project trunk-edumatic-3-framework-client
net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.CruiseControlException: svn process exited with error code 1
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.util.CommandExecutor.executeAndWait(CommandExecutor.java:119)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.util.Commandline.executeAndWait(Commandline.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.bootstrappers.SVNBootstrapper.bootstrap(SVNBootstrapper.java:134)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.bootstrap(Project.java:760)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.build(Project.java:192)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.execute(Project.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.ProjectConfig.execute(ProjectConfig.java:402)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.ProjectWrapper.run(ProjectWrapper.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

---

The problem does not occur when executing an update trough the command line svn or the windows tortoise svn client.
The server accesses the Internet trough a proxy, which is configured in tortoise svn's network settings. 
Is there a way to tell cruisecontrol to use that same proxy?

Any thoughts?

Bert

Answer (score 2):

If you are running cruise on a windows XP machine, you can try editing the proxy settings in the file C:\Documents and Settings\user.name\Application Data\Subversion\server.

I am not sure about the equivalent files in the other operating systesm though, but in general look for application data and the subversion directory within. This folder gets created the first time you ran subversion client so it should be there in your cruise machine already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any possibility for providing 'proxy' argument to svn command. Neither in [the SVN bootstrapper source](http://cruisecontrol.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cruisecontrol/trunk/cruisecontrol/main/src/net/sourceforge/cruisecontrol/bootstrappers/SVNBootstrapper.java?revision=3959&view=markup) nor in the [config ref](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#svnbootstrapper).

But...

You could always:

- file it as a [request to CruiseControl](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa),
- and/or... try to fool the CruiseControl by preparing another version of `cvs` executable. Maybe a batch file called `cvs.bat` that would simply call `cvs` executable with additional parameters specifying the proxy. I haven't tried that.